# Remove query from URL before $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Tags: php, html

On success or fail of a form submission I am using the following. The resulting url appears as `http://example.com/directory/?success=false`

The problem I am having is that when a user attempts to submit the form again after correcting validation error the resulting url becomes `http://example.com/directory/?success=false?success=true` -  I need it to clear any querystring first. How could I do this?

**PHP**

```
# Redirect user to error message
 header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . '?success=false');
}
```

Comment: You should not be using the referrer for this at all. Please go research how unreliable that value is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `explode()` to break the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']` string to get rid of the existing `$_GET` arguments:

```
$bits = explode('?',$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']);
$redirect = $bits[0];

# Redirect user to error message
header('Location: ' . $redirect . '?success=true');
```

Comment: No problem. You're crazy like a fox. (verruktfuchs)

Comment: It shall be `HTTP_REFERER`. Unfortunately the edit queue is full. Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
$i = strchr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], "?");
$address = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 0, $i);
header('Location: ' . $address . '?success=false');
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this but for some reason it kept referring back to the local directory as opposed to the referring page. Problem solved now, thanks for your help anyway.